# Return array of values with MYSQL SELECT

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can MySQL Nested Select return list of results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524848/can-mysql-nested-select-return-list-of-results)

I have one table containing the `users` (id, name) and another one containing `courseAttrs` a user has applied to (userID,courseID). I would like to select all users and have this select return the name and a comma separated list of courseIDs the user has applied to. What is a possible solution?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried selecting all courses where it would return all users and their courses. Example: if I have 2 users, the first one has 2 `courseAttr` entries and the second one has 4 then the query would return 6 rows, each with a different courseID but not comma separated. I could handle this with PHP but I am assuming there is a simpler solution through MYSQL. I have the feeling `JOIN ON` could help but I don't know how the `JOIN` command works.

Comment: I found a similar question with which I was able to get the result I intended. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524848/can-mysql-nested-select-return-list-of-results

Answer (score 1):

You should check the manual of mysql, so, as far as you explain u should create the query for two tables...  you can use the procedures of mysql to get results.. u can always use a foreach to read all values, and if u want an specific kind of array you can create it meanwhile the loop is running through your object/array returned by mysql

I think if you create an array (like i think u want to create) with the form (name, courseid, courseid, courseid) u might get a mess with all the data, and might create an array per user. I think the best is to recieve the objects or arrays that u get from the query.

for the query, assuming you have an associative field, you can do something like this

select * from user, courseAttrs where user.courseattr = courseattr.id_couse_attr

If you use mysql_fetch_object

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $row->user_id;
    echo $row->fullname;

}
```

mysql_fetch_assoc() returns associative array:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
}
```

mysql_fetch_array() returns array

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row[0];
    echo $row[1] ;
}
```

Comment: the `$row` result I would like to get from MYSQL would be `array("name"=>"Joe", "courseIDs"=>"1,2,3,6");` The `courseIDs` string could then be run through `explode("1,2,3,6")` which I could then process further. If I am not able to find anything I will just implement it with PHP.

Comment: but what if u you have more than one row of results?? would u create another array?