# Android SQLite: combine multiple rows into one

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have two SQLite tables:
- users:

```
id    username    age
1     jack        24
2     lisa        19
```

- images:

```
id    username    image
1     jack        jackImg1.jpg
2     jack        jackImg2.jpg
3     lisa        lisaImg1.jpg
```

I use LEFT JOIN to get all jack's images:

```
SELECT users.*, images.image FROM users
LEFT JOIN images ON images.username = users.username
WHERE users.username = 'jack';
```

the result is like this:

```
id    username    age    image
1     jack        24     jackImg1.jpg
1     jack        24     jackImg2.jpg
```

But I'd like to get a result like this:

```
id    username    age    image1          image2
1     jack        24     jackImg1.jpg    jackImg2.jpg
```

How can I achieve a result like above table?
**Note:** ***the number of images can vary from zero to any number(like 15, 20,...)***

Comment: That's not how SQL works. See how you would have to generate new column names `image1` and `image2`? What if you query several users with a different number of attached images?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524848/can-mysql-nested-select-return-list-of-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not provide such functionality to pivot or unpivot tables.
What you can do is group by user and use the [`group_concat()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) aggregate function to achieve a similar result:

```
SELECT 
  u.id, u.username, u.age, 
  group_concat(i.image, ' ') images 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN images i
ON i.username = u.username
WHERE u.username = 'jack'
GROUP BY u.id, u.username, u.age
```

I used space as a separator between the images, you can use any char you want.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uNJ9np9VqseBtkhrUo9deY/0).
Results:

```
| id  | username | age | images                    |
| --- | -------- | --- | ------------------------- |
| 1   | jack     | 24  | jackImg1.jpg jackImg2.jpg |
```